# How to get translated month labels

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I think, this labels and its translations are available, but I don't know where. I found nothing in the "Translate Interface" seach.

So here's my question:
is there a way to get translated month labels more elegant as like `t('january')` ?

Comment: Look again. Last time I did it, all months (and days) were there.

Comment: you are right, after inspecting the .po files, I found the labels.

Comment: Month names are not added automatically. For an elegant solution, look here: https://drupal.org/comment/8251325#comment-8251325

Answer (score 0):

Normally date labels (months, day, etc. in short and long version) should be translated automatically according to the language configured for Drupal interface (*admin/config/regional/settings*).

However, in case there might have been an issue somewhere, with [Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) and the module [Localization update](https://drupal.org/project/l10n_update) enabled the following command forces the translation to be updated and it solved the issue in my case:

```
drush l10n-update
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on GZBK's answer, I had to do following to get things right:

drush l10n-update-refresh

drush l10n-update

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the month and weekname labels using the translation interface at http://example.com/admin/config/regional/translate/translate

The search is case sensitive.

To ensure that the month names or week day labels are available for translation, you can fashion a custom module such as suggested in this comment: https://drupal.org/comment/8251325#comment-8251325

Strings are only available for translation after the first time they are processed by the t() function in Drupal 7.